# When an iOS app is pulled from the App Store, do subscriptions get canceled?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

Our app is being pulled from the Apple App Store. We have a large number of recurring subscribers who could continue to use the app for some time after this, since they would still have the app, but will the subscriptions be pulled by Apple at the same time?

I have tried to find information about this on the web, but it's obviously a pretty edge case. A few SO questions mention that normal in-app-purchases might remain available, but I can't find any mention of recurring subscriptions at all.